# Connection between number theory and operator theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hecke-operators

I was wondering if there is any connection between number theory and operator theory.
Especially the applications of Hardy spaces, de branges-Rovnyak spaces, Dirichlet spaces in number theory. For example to study modular forms, and etc.Something except Riemann Hypothesis.

Does anyone know any books or papers about that?

Comment: Cross posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813757/connection-between-operator-theory-and-number-theory